# Convert CFBundleVersion to NSNumber & compare it

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, info.plist

Before asking why: I'm writing an extension that observes the `CFBundleVersion` of an app & then compares it to old version that isn't supported by the extension.

Here's what I do to compare.

```
CFStringRef _version = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"],
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@" !*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

NSString *versionString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(_version);

NSNumberFormatter * nsFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nsFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber * installedVersion = [nsFormatter numberFromString:versionString];
NSNumber * incompatibleVersion = [nsFormatter numberFromString:@"6.1.0"];


if (installedVersion <= incompatibleVersion) {

    NSLog(@"This was triggered");

}
```

The code works great, but only when there are two decimals. For instance, if I set the `CFBundleVersion` to `6.0` or `5.0` The code is not triggered. Is there a better way of comparing? I don't understand why it's thinking `5.0` is greater than `6.1.0`

Suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, I searched but didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously can't treat it as one number, so treat it as a set of numbers with a separator. Then, you can use `componentsSeparatedByString:@"."` and process each of the numbers separately.

Be sure to check the count of the components. If one number has more components than the other you should fall back to default values (`0`) if you haven't already got a result from the algorithm.

Loop over the components and compare each part.

Answer (score 2):

Versions in the format major.minor.patch cannot generally be represented as a single number. It's best to compare the strings using ...

```
[version1 compare:version2 options:NSNumericSearch];
```

This only works if the number of components is always the same.